# how to start a database using mserver in the monetdb

Tags: monetdb

I want to bind the program in one cpu when I using monetdb,so I think I can start the monetdb with mserver for this purpose,but I do not know how to do,if my database named newdb,what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply ....

First create dbform using

```
 monetdbd create ~/my_dbform
monetdbd start  ~/my_dbform
```

Then you have to create database

```
monetdb create newdb
monetdb release newdb
```

Thus u can create a mserver .

For client do

```
mclient -u monetdb -d mydb
```

with password as

> monetdb

Answer (score -1):

it is empty when you create a database,you can insert data or sql> \< voc_dump.sql
https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/Tutorial/Windows